# View K2 `v2.6.9` category items in joomla 3.4.2 front-end

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have the component `2K` installed on my `joomla!`. I have a category called `news`. I want a direct link to list the items in that category. I don't want to add a menu item anywhere in my site. This is a stand alone page that is accessible only via a direct link.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure how I stumbled upon this, but

`http://www.domain.com/component/k2/content/{category_id}-{category_name}/`

Answer (score 0):

Create special menu for hidden link (dont associate any menu module with it).

Now just create in this menu links what you want - it will not apear anywhere on site but will be accessible via a direct link.